# bootstrap icon text is dim

Tags: forms, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I have three bootstrap buttons in a row, all inside of a form:

1. a `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">` that submits the form
2. a `<a class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit</a>` button right next to it.
3. a `<a class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-plus icon-white"></i> New</a>` button right next to that one.

For some reason, the "Edit" text is in gray, while the text of the other two buttons is white -- any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: should note that it's only dim until you hover over it, and then it's bright white again

Comment: did you look with firebug? you might have some styling applied to your edit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may either look upon as suggested in @Marronsuisse comment or you can use

```
<a class="btn btn-inverse" style="color:#FFF">
<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit</a>
```

Also, beg me pardon, but it might be looking as gray to your eyes due to it's black background..you can verify the same with this

```
<a class="btn btn-inverse" style="font-weight:bolder">
<i class="icon-edit icon-white"></i> Edit</a>
```